# Erro ao fazer push no gitbash

Tags: git, github

Está mostrando o seguinte erro no console do *git bash*:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

> ```
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
> ```

Alguém sabe me dizer o por quê?

Comment: Você cadastrou sua chave pública (normalmente reside em `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, onde `~` é a pasta _home_ do usuário) na sua conta do GitHub?

Comment: Sim Jeferson, tenho uma chave cadastrada lá.

Comment: A chave cadastrada é a mesma que o git na linha de comando usa? Outro ponto, você subiu a chave pública, não a privada, certo? Confundir essas chaves já gerou problema com colegas aqui do trabalho. Também foi problemático gerar as chaves pelo `Putty`, mas pelo `openssh-keygen` sempre funciona

Comment: Putz cara agora não sei qual chave é, nem sabia disto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta mensagem de erro pode ter [diferentes causas](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/). Vou listar algumas, nas quais você precisa conferir:

- Chave SSH [inexistente](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys) na sua máquina
- Chave SSH não está [adicionada no ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
- ssh-agent não está [em execução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984258/2387977)
- Sua chave pública usada no SSH não está [atrelada a sua conta no Github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- Uma chave incorreta está atrelada a sua conta no Github.